# Android:TextView is not set on top of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm designing my application. In which I want to set `TextView` on top of an `ImageView` without any correction of any Layout. `TextView` is on top of `ImageView` like other two Buttons. Is it possible to set `TextView` on `ImageView`. In my code `TextView` is hidden behind `ImageView`. Here is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/call_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receive1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/acceptxml" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rejectxml" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> My Actual Code is like this. this is perfectly working in application. but when i change this like your code. so its contain error.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/call_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_photo" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receive1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/acceptxml" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rejectxml" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just using FrameLayout ?

Comment: can u please edit my code..??? @FaroukTouzi

Comment: @user3699143 : I put an answer just below.

Comment: @user3699143  `In which I want to set TextView on top of an ImageView without any correction of any Layout??` How is it possible without changing your layout?

Comment: i want same as like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6YfJb3plGeckpwbURBOHludWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this and let me know.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"    
            android:textColor="#ff0000"     
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"       
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receive1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check my question. "without change any layout"... i want same it is. but my project is not work due to change in layout.

Comment: Your project is not working?? What do you mean by `not working`? What is happening? Is it showing any error? I have just moved the `TextView` to the `RelativeLayout` which has `ImageView`. How is it possible without changing your layout?. Let us know why it is not working, someone will help you out.

Comment: in existing code when i press cancel button so activity is close. and now in this code when i press cancel button at that time activity is force close. @Aniruddha

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".85" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receive1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanku 4 your replay... but in this code layout is change. so it is not working for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hugh Jackman"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(201) 555-5555"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receive1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:background="@drawable/acceptxml" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rejectxml" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i want full screen image. like same is this.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6YfJb3plGeckpwbURBOHludWc/edit?usp=sharing  @Haresh

Comment: it was same error in my project. check my question Running code and than edit @Haresh

Comment: i have mailed u on hareshchhelana@gmail.com id.